# Fit Subscribe bar on 1 line for smaller screen size

Tags: html, css, mobile, screen

I am trying to adjust the css so that the bar on the top of the website fits on one line. Right now the field appears on 2 lines when the screen is small. (on mobile as well as when you resize browser window).
Same goes for the menu.

If anyone can help me with this i will be very thankful.

http://healthyeatingandliving.ca/

Comment: try to add your html code and css here it would help us to find a solution for you ,,,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
#nsu-head p.form_label{
text-transform: uppercase;
 padding-right: 60px;
 margin-top: -9px;
 margin-left: 0;/* this will affect */
}
```

***`in related media query`***

and you can write a media query for 22in like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width:21in) and (max-width:23in){/* or other size */
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-right: 60px;
    margin-top: -9px;
    margin-left: 0;/*your value*/
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Doing that shifts everything in the "green bar" to the left.I have a 22 inch screen and a 17 inch . on the 17 it seems fine but on the 22 inch the text in the bar is all the way to the left and not centered. any idea?

Comment: as much as I know in this situation you can right a media query for 22 inch and set different values for element...

Comment: Whoops, i totally missed the part where you said media queries. Let me  take a look at those since there are none defines right now. Thanks man.

Comment: OK... I'm glad you find the answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, though I don't think it will be possible to keep everything in "1 line". You'll have to use media queries to target different parts. In the code you posted it looks like you have a lot of styles overlapping. Try to simplify things like margin and padding, instead of having margin on a lot of elements, try to identify those element before hand and apply a padding to their parent. That way you just do it once.

http://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/B2rS6/11/

**CSS:**

```
    /* Makes padding not add extra width to parent element */
    * { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

    /* Rows (clear fix - This is like pressing the "return" key down to the next line) */
    .row:before, .row:after { content: " "; display: table; }
    .row:after { clear: both; }
    .row { *zoom: 1; clear: both;  }

    /* Large Screens */
    .nsu-header-wrapper { background: #39b54a; width: 100%; }
    .nsu-header { color: white; margin: 0 auto; padding: 1em 0; width: 90%; } /* or whatever you want your width to be */
    .form_label { width: 40%; float: left; display: block; }
    .nsu-form { float: right; text-align: left; display: inline-block; }
    .nsu-form p { float: left; padding: 0 0 0 1em; }

    /* Media Query (For tablet) */
    @media screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Adjust this width to meet your needs */
        .nsu-header { text-align: center; }
        .form_label { width: 100%; float: left; display: block; }
        .nsu-form { float: none; display: inline-block; }
    }

    /* Media Query (For mobile) */
    @media screen and (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 768px) { /* Adjust this width to meet your needs */
        .nsu-header { text-align: center; }
        .form_label { width: 100%; float: left; display: block; }
        .nsu-form { width: 100%; float: left; display: block; }
        .nsu-form * { width: 100%; float: left; display: block; }
    }
```

As you can imagine, things can get pretty tricky with media queries... I've spent a lot of time with grid systems trying to pick out the "best".. and I couldn't really find something that made the most sense to me.

So I created my own: http://oneillwebs.com/grid/

Feel free to use it in your project or as a learning tool! It's created with percentage based media queries so any screen you're on will fit right. hope this helps

Comment: I would like to thank you for so much work. I will definitely go through this and get some solution running.

Comment: And your grid thing is amazing.

Comment: Thanks! It took me a hot minute to create! (feel free to check it as your answer :)

Comment: He , i just had a small question. What if i dont be responsive ( since my website isnt). I would rather have it on one line and let people zoom out to read it . Does that make sense?

Comment: If that's the case just change the width of .nsu-header to 940px and remove the mobile/tablet media queries

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for your help. It worked! now everything is on one line. You are awesome.